# When 2 computer interact over a network connection then first they have to make a socket connection?

Tags: sockets, computer-science

Please answers in yes or no. This will solve my doubt.
1. Is a post/get request sent from computer-1 to Computer-2 then first they have to make a socket connection?
2. When 2 computers connect with ssh then first they have to make a socket connection , then only then can talk to each other ?

Comment: Sockets are a common *abstraction*, frequently encountered when working with TCP/UDP protocols. There's nothing to stop someone using some other abstraction and, of course, there are other protocols.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever  that didn't answer my question.. for you i am simplyfing the question ....is it for every protocol  underlying mechanism has to make a socket connection ?

Comment: Back in the prehistoric era (i.e. 1980's and 1990's) the most common way for computers to interact was via modem.  No TCP/IP stack was present on either computer, and therefore no sockets were involved.  Instead, each computer ran purpose-built software that communicated with the serial port directly.

That said, whenever computers are communicating *using a TCP/IP stack*, sockets are the software abstraction used to manage that communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please answers in yes or no. This will solve my doubt.
[ok]

1. Is a post/get request sent from computer-1 to Computer-2 then first they have to make a socket connection?
   In this case, Yes, but if request is going from browser then it do for you.You can see thr url for get and post have the port number in them. If not mentioned the default port is 80, in general. For example If you use WebSphere Application Server, the default port is 9081 or 80 if IBM HTTP Server is configured.
2. When 2 computers connect with ssh then first they have to make a socket connection , then only then can talk to each other ?
   In this Case, again Yes, the port is 22 in ssh

Answer (score 1):

The examples you give involve network connections and sockets are a common abstraction used when communicating over modern computer networks; however, other abstractions could be used. This is what Damien_The_Unbeliever is saying in the comments. For example, you could ask whether for loops are the only way to iterate over an array. The answer is the same: for loops are a common abstraction to loop over elements of an array, but there are other equivalent (in a machine-code sense) methods of doing so using other abstractions.

More fundamentally, computers can communicate with each other without using networks at all. You could have computers communicate over an interface consisting of webcams and monitors; sending is accomplished by putting something on the screen and receiving is accomplished by receiving the video feed. You could do the same with microphones and speakers. You could do the same with robotic arms, keyboards and mice. Two computers can communicate with each other using a human courier; my work and home computers do it regularly! Computers could write letters and mail them, deliver them or use carrier pigeons to send them to other computers designed to accept information in those formats.

Comment: Just because carrier pigeons are involved, that doesn't *preclude* sockets also being involved. Bear in mind [RFC 1149](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149) *has* had at least one implementation. (Although I don't believe they got as far as interoperability testing)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever IPoPigeon? You know the latency might be rough but it seems like the bandwidth could be pretty good.

Comment: @Dr.JonesWhite In the same sense that soup cannot be consumed except with a spoon, absolutely.